# Lens maker formula and lens formula gives different values of focal length. Where is the problem?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Lens maker formula is given as

$\frac{1}{f}= (n-1)(\frac{1}{R} - \frac{1}{R'})$, $n$ = refractive index

If I take $R=R'$ for symmetrical biconvex thin lens then using sign convention it gives

$$\frac{1}{f} = (n-1)\frac{2}{R}$$

Again lens formula is given as

$$\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{v} -\frac{1}{u}$$

Now if object is at center of curvature then u=v=R then using sign convention lens formula gives

$$\frac{1}{f} = \frac{2}{R}$$

Where is the problem in my understanding?

Comment: The problem is $u=v\ne R$

Comment: Are approximations causing problem? I think for thin lenses if object is at R distance then u≈R.

Comment: @mmesser314 thank you for the answer that does make sense.

Comment: Not taking $n$ into account is causing the problem. For a lens made of air, $u = v = \infty$, no matter what $R$ is. Two lenses of the same shape made of materials with two different indices of refraction will have two different $f$'s and two different $u$ and $v$ values. Note that $u = v$ comes from a choice of where you put the object. If you make a different choice $u \ne v$,

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I realise that I have mistakenly taken u=v=2f=R.

Comment: $\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{R}\neq\frac{1}{2R}$ it might come as a surprise but its $\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{R}=\frac{2}{R}$

Comment: @José Andrade Thanks for pointing that mistake. I don't know how I missed that although I wanted to know if R=2f is also true for lenses as well so I put certain values to obtain results but got lost in calculations.

Comment: Now I have edited the question and I accept the answers given in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the lens maker equation, that relates various physical parameter of a "thin" lens to the focal length of the lens, to an equation that relates where the image of an object appears relative to the lens given it's focal length.

Your lens makers equations are fine. The equation 1/ = 1/ − 1/  relates where the image will be formed.  If you want the object and the image to be the same distance from the lens, then indeed U= V= R = F/2.

The result is not in contradiction with the Lens Maker's formula result because these two equations are describing two different scenarios.

Comment: But u= v= R is not possible in all cases. Only u=v=2f is certain for lenses.

Comment: Assuming the focal length is positive, every time you place the object at 2f, the image occurs at 2f. Easy to verify. 

The problem is that you want to force the image to be at R given that the object is at R.  This puts a constraint on f to be R/2.  If you place the object at R, but allow the image to be anywhere then you free yourself from this

Comment: Yes I can understand that if I force u=v=R then R=2f but then what is the correct solution to my original question? Why 2 different scenarios? Why not in same problem?